# Tabindex skipps over Link

Tags: accessibility, usability, tabindex

My HTML5 tabindex skips over a link element. Even when using `tabindex=0`, the tabindex skips right over and ignores the `<a>` element. AFAIK `<a>` should already be in the tabindex (even without the `tabindex` attribute) as long as it has a `href` attribute.

**sample code:**

`<a href="/game" tabindex="0">Hello world!</a>`

Comment: Mac or PC? Do you have event handlers in your javascript? How do you know it's skipped? Do you see the focus move from the element before the link to the element after the link? Does your real link have text inside it?  (Your example doesn't).

Comment: @slugolicious happens on both Mac and PC, no matter what browser. No event handlers in JS. The elements before and after are focusable. Yes, my link does have text in it (edited the question).

Comment: Do you have a live example where the problem is reproduced? As such, except that tabindex=0 is superfluous, it doesn't look bad. Also, go have a look at the options of your browser, I know that there are options to enable/disable tab navigation inside pages.

Comment: @QuentinC's comments about browser options to enable tab navigation was one reason I asked about Mac or PC. In Safari, you have enable tabbing to all elements. It's really stupid requirement that Apple has persisted keeping. You can try Option+Tab if you don't want to change the setting. See https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keyboard-and-other-shortcuts-cpsh003/mac#apd075d0dec05a54.  But if you're having a problem on the PC too, then the Safari setting is obviously not the problem. You'll have to provide a codepen.io example (or similar). Tabbing to links is a basic feature that works.

Comment: I have the same issue - but just on Windows.  When tabbing through the page, the "Policies" link in the footer is skipped.   I can't see any obvious reason in the code why that link is any different than the others. 
 Works fine in Chrome and Edge on Mac, but Chrome on Windows skips that link. 
 See https://comptroller.texas.gov/taxes/training/